# SQL Server data and log file location on single physical drive

Tags: sql-server, partition

I have just got my hands on a dedicated hosted Windows Server 2012 R2 which has had SQL Server 2014 installed.  The server has a single 2Tb drive (C:) which I assume is a standard hard-drive, rather than SSD, although this is purely a guess.

I've always been of the understanding that placing the data and log files for a database on different drives is important... and I believe the reason for that is for efficiency when writing contiguous data to the log file so the head doesn't have to move constantly.

If my understanding is correct, does it make sense to partition a single drive into multiple ones simply to put the log file in a different location?

My gut feeling is that it is pointless, and if anything will actually **increase** the distance the head has to move between partitions?

Should I partition the disk, or would I be better just leaving the data and log files on the C: drive?

(Or am I asking a question that simply can't be answered with the limited information I've give here?!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating multiple volumes on the same physical disk for database and log separation won't change the fact that the I/O patterns for the physical disk will remain mixed; random and sequential, so I don't really see any value in doing this from a performance perspective.

Comment: The only benefit I can think of is you will have multiple logical disk queues.